# VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration is not available on your system

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox

I am trying to find out if my system has VT-x with the CPU-G tool but I am not able to see what I expect. It is because my virtualbox gave a message [VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration is not available on your system. Certain guests (e.g. OS/2 and QNX) require this feature and will fail to boot without it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DdIu.png) .I run Ubuntu 16.04LTS. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can run `lscpu` and see if any virtualization is enabled. I bet it is not since VB throws this error.

Virtualization may be disabled in BIOS or may be not supported by the CPU.

Comment: Dosn't help much.